# How to add a new item to every index in the array -php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, variables, laravel-8

`var_export($res)` is an array as below.

```
array(0 =>(object) array('user' => NULL,
                        'courseId' => 18,),
      1 =>(object) array('user' =>(object) array('id' => 1,
                                                'name' => 'admin',
                                                'files' => NULL,),
                        'courseId' => 1,),
    )
```

At every index in this array, i need to calculate `count` using the `courseId` and add a new item called `count` to every index. i used the below code. And the expected end result is an array of objects , not an object of objects.

```
$res=json_decode($response);
foreach ($res as $key ) {                   
    $count = MyCourse::where('course_id', $key->courseId)->distinct('student_id')->count();
    $res['count'] = $count; 
}
return response()->json(['data' => $res,'statusCode' => 200], 200);
```

the above code shows the below data. it added `count` as a new index in the array not added it as anew item to every index of the array. Also, it is returning an result in the form of object of objects.How can i fix this?

```
    {
        "0": {
            "user": null,
            "courseId": 18
        },
        "1": {
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "admin",
                "files": null
            },
            "courseId": 1
        },
        "count": 1
    }
```

**Expected End Result**:

```
  [
       {
            "user": null,
            "courseId": 18,
            "count": 20
        },
        {
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "admin",
                "files": null
            },
            "courseId": 1,
            "count": 10
        }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your foreach loop, `$key` is each of your objects containing `courseId`.

Instead of adding `count` to `$res`, add it to `$key` like so:

```
foreach ($res as &$key ) {                   
    $count = MyCourse::where('course_id', $key->courseId)->distinct('student_id')->count();
    $key->count = $count; // set it to $key instead of $res
}
```

If you want the results to be arrays instead of objects, pass `true` as the second argument to `json_decode` like so:

```
$res = json_decode($response, true); // associative array instead of object
```

and then edit the foreach to handle it as arrays instead:

```
foreach ($res as $key ) {                   
    $count = MyCourse::where('course_id', $key['courseId'])->distinct('student_id')->count();
    $key['count'] = $count; // set it to $key instead of $res
}
```

Comment: it works when assigning like this - `$key->count = $count; ` . but it outputs only 1 array as this `{"user": { "id": 1, "name": "admin","files": null},"courseId": 1,"count": 1 }`

Comment: Make sure you are still returning `$res` in `return response()->json(['data' => $res,'statusCode' => 200], 200);`

Answer (score 0):

In your case you want to set the count field for `$key` instead of `$res`

Your foreach loop should look like this:

```
foreach ($res as $key ) {                   
    $count = MyCourse::where('course_id', $key->courseId)->distinct('student_id')->count();
    $key->count = $count; 
}
```

This would output:

```
    {
        "0": {
            "user": null,
            "courseId": 18,
            "count": 20
        },
        "1": {
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "admin",
                "files": null
            },
            "courseId": 1,
            "count": 10
        }
    }
```

Comment: this gives me the error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` on the line `$key['count'] = $count; `

Comment: Oops, sorry, I would edit my answer. You would need to refer to count as an object field with ->

Comment: It will work correctly only if `foreach ($res as &$key)`